# Do I have to include list of all libraries on UI in website project?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have noticed that each external library has their own licence like (Apache 2.0) etc.

For example the EJS Templating library has a Apache 2.0 Licence.Does that mean that whenever I use any third party library if I was building an online admin panel/website which uses ejs which could be commercial or non-commercial website,I have to specifically mention the libraries(like EJS) used somewhere on the user interface viewable to the user?